# Load local font by using css

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, font-face

I am hosting a javascript project on locally and trying to use the local font, but it seem not loaded, here is my style.css code, ipixregular is the font i am trying to use, may I know what might be the problem? and do I need to refere it in html? thanks

```css
@import "@fontsource/press-start-2p/index.css";
@import "@16bits/nes.css/css/nes.min.css";

@font-face {
  font-family: 'ipixregular';
  src: url('front/ipix-webfont.eot');
  src: url('front/ipix-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('front/ipix-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('front/ipix-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('front/ipix-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('front/ipix-webfont.svg#ipixregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;

}

* {
  font-family: ipixregular
}

.nes-btn {
  font-family: "Press Start 2P";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@import loads the font style rules
@font-face loads the font

I do not understand why you have the rule
font-family: "Press Start 2P";
as that is not a valid font family.

You could try
body * {font-family: ipixregular;}

Comment: It's not clear what your solution is here. Please include some formatted code.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you are using "front" instead of "font" in your URLs, to be clear - is this the right folder name? Could simply be a typo.

I.e., from: `url('front/ipix-webfont.eot')` to: `url('font/ipix-webfont.eot')`